# Groovy: I need to remove all instances of a value that is duplicated in a list

Tags: groovy

So I have the following list `def list = [1, 2, 3, 1, 4]`. Any value that is being duplicated and all of the instances of that value (in this case '1') need to be removed from the list.

The only thing I found is this: `def uniqueId = list.unique()` but unfortunately this only removes one of the values of that duplicate and I end up with `uniqueId = [1, 2, 3, 4]` and this doesn't exactly help me. I need my final output to be `uniqueId = [2, 3, 4]`.

Anyone knows a solution to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting!

So we can do this: (comments inline)

```
def result = list.groupBy() // This will give us a map [1:[1, 1], 2:[2], 3:[3], 4:[4]]
    .findResults {
        // if there is only one entry, return the key
        // Otherwise, return null (so nothing is added to the result)
        it.value.size() == 1 ? it.key : null
    }
```

This gives us `[2, 3, 4]`

Another way is to use `countBy()` instead of `groupBy()`:

```
def result = list.countBy { it } // This will give us a map [1:2, 2:1, 3:1, 4:1]
    .findResults {
        // if the value is 1, return the key
        // Otherwise, return null (so nothing is added to the result)
        it.value == 1 ? it.key : null
    }
```

Same result

Comment: That is perfect. Thank you so much.

Comment: @Cata Does `list.findAll { list.count(it) == 1 }` also give you the desired results?

Comment: Would you say that was a better way @JeffScottBrown? I guess it depends on the real nature of `list` 

Comment: "Would you say that was a better way @JeffScottBrown?" - I would not, at least not objectively better in all ways.

Comment: Just checking, I always trust the Word of Jeff 